# Calling templated function of a nested class of derived class out of a nested class of a base class

Tags: c++, templates

I wasn't sure about a proper title. It does seem confusing. Sorry for that.
I am not a programmer. So please, bear with me. I am surely using some terminology wrongly.

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. Have a base class A_base with some nested class (sub-class?) defined in it (B_base). A_base will have all kinds of common functions that do not require specialization. The nested class is providing some interface for communication with another application (there are callbacks in it, which I define according to my needs).

```
class A_base
{
public:

void a_function()
{
    std::cout << "This is a base a_function\n" ;
}

void a_b_function();

class B_base
{
  public:

  void b_function()
  {
    std::cout << "This is a base b_function\n" ;
  }

  void b_a_function();

  virtual void b_c_function1(){return;};
  virtual void b_c_function2(){return;};

  B_base(const std::string& name_in, A_base* ptr_A_in):
    name(name_in), ptr_A(ptr_A_in)
  {}

  protected:
    const std::string name;
    A_base* ptr_A;
};

B_base* b_object;

A_base(const std::string& name_in):
    b_object(new B_base(name_in, this)), name(name_in)
{}

protected:
    const std::string name;
};

void A_base::a_b_function()
{
    b_object->b_function();
}

void A_base::B_base::b_a_function()
  {
    ptr_A->a_function();
  }
```

2. Derive a templated class out of A_base (A_derived) with some additional specialized functionality and another nested class in it (C_class, which is also templated). I chose this to optimize the latency of my program. It doesn't have to be always lightning fast, but there's one particular path in the logic that must be as fast as possible. Therefore, I am trying to eliminate unnecessary branching by using templates.

```
enum Side{BB=0,SS=1};

template<bool B>
class A_derived : public A_base
{
public:    
void a_function()
{
    std::cout << "This is a derived a_function\n" ;
}    

template<Side S>
class C_class
{
  public:

  void c_function();      

  C_class(const std::string& name_in, A_derived* ptr_A_in):
  name(name_in), ptr_A(ptr_A_in)
  {}

  protected:
  const std::string name;
  A_derived* ptr_A;
};

C_class<Side::BB> c_object_bb;
C_class<Side::SS> c_object_ss;

A_derived(const std::string& name_in):
  A_base(name_in), c_object_bb(name_in, this), c_object_ss(name_in, this)
{}

};
```

3. Here I am defining the specialized functions (the ones that are supposed to be fast):

```
template<> template<>
void A_derived<false>::C_class<Side::BB>::c_function()
{
      std::cout << "This is a false-BB c_function\n" ;  
}

template<> template<>
void A_derived<false>::C_class<Side::SS>::c_function()
{
      std::cout << "This is a false-SS c_function\n" ;  
}

template<> template<>
void A_derived<true>::C_class<Side::BB>::c_function()
{
      std::cout << "This is a true-BB c_function\n" ;  
}

template<> template<>
void A_derived<true>::C_class<Side::SS>::c_function()
{
      std::cout << "This is a true-SS c_function\n" ;  
}
```

4. And on top of that there's a need to be able to call some of the specialized functions out of a method of a nested class B_base. The specialized functions belong to a C_class. Hence, B_base knows nothing about it. But I am trying to circumvent this by casting the A_base pointer into A_derived pointer. I know for sure what kind of A_derived will be used in each case.

The problem is, the C_class function has to be called depending on the version of A_derived that is used. But B_base itself is not a templated class. So, clearly the following is not working the way I want it to work:

```
void  A_derived<false>::B_base::b_c_function1()
{
    static_cast<A_derived<false>*>(ptr_A)->c_object_bb.c_function();
}

void A_derived<false>::B_base::b_c_function2()
{    
    static_cast<A_derived<false>*>(ptr_A)->c_object_ss.c_function();
}

void  A_derived<true>::B_base::b_c_function1()
{
    static_cast<A_derived<true>*>(ptr_A)->c_object_bb.c_function();
}

void A_derived<true>::B_base::b_c_function2()
{    
    static_cast<A_derived<true>*>(ptr_A)->c_object_ss.c_function();
}
```

It just complains about redefining functions. And if I add template<> syntaxis it complains that there is not template out there. And it's kinda true. Can't blame the compiler for this.

Can you please suggest me a reasonable solution? How can I call a templated function of a nested class of a derived class from a method of a nested class of a base class?

Thank you.

**Added**: So, one person suggested in the comments I should use virtual functions instead. After some thinking I decided to clarify. B_base has its functions as virtual, actually. And this is not my code. I just have to deal with it. The reason virtual functions are of little help is that I cannot simply derive my A_base off B_base (due to some reasons). And for the most of B_base's functions I am fine with some common definitions. However, there are 10% of B_base's functions that I want to be specialized, depending on A_derived that is being instantiated.
My back up solution is to not use B_base at all but rather have some derived B_derived that'd be fully defined inside my A_derived. Unfortunately that would mean writing an infinite amount of useless code. Because most of B_base functions do not depend on type of A_derived.

Comment: I think "nested class" would be the proper term for B_base.

Comment: It's a bit abstract with all the A, B, and C names, but to me it looks a lot like you are trying to invent a new way to replace virtual functions. So instead of a vtable pointer you have an explicit pointer where you call `...(ptr_A)->c_object_ss.c_function()`. But that is still an indirection.

Comment: @Bo Persson The thing is, I am deliberately trying to avoid using virtual functions in some particular part of my code. When I create objects of my classes I actually create particular specialized objects that do not have to look up for a proper function in vtable but rather call directly the only version of the function that is appropriate in their case.

Comment: @ttemple Cheers. Replaced it.